# How can I divide rdd to specific number of rdds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have the below code which generates RDD from a text file:

```
val data = sparkContext.textfile(path)
val k = 3
```

How can I divide data into k unique RDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use [`RDD.randomSplit`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala)which will divide existing RDD based on weights passed in the parameters and return Array of RDDs.

The internal working will be like below...

```
/**
 * Randomly splits this RDD with the provided weights.
 *
 * @param weights weights for splits, will be normalized if they don't sum to 1
 * @param seed random seed
 *
 * @return split RDDs in an array
 */
def randomSplit(weights: Array[Double], seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): Array[RDD[T]] = {
  require(weights.forall(_ >= 0),
    s"Weights must be nonnegative, but got ${weights.mkString("[", ",", "]")}")
  require(weights.sum > 0,
    s"Sum of weights must be positive, but got ${weights.mkString("[", ",", "]")}")

  withScope {
    val sum = weights.sum
    val normalizedCumWeights = weights.map(_ / sum).scanLeft(0.0d)(_ + _)
    normalizedCumWeights.sliding(2).map { x =>
    randomSampleWithRange(x(0), x(1), seed)
  }.toArray
}
```

***NOTE : weights weights for splits, will be normalized if they don't sum to 1***

*Based on the above behavior I created a sample snippet like below which was working  :*

```
def getDoubleWeights(numparts:Int) : Array[Double] = {
  Array.fill[Double](numparts)(1.0d)
}
```

caller would be like....

```
val rddWithNumParts : Array[RDD] = yourRDD.randomSplit(getDoubleWeights(yourRDD.partitions.length))
```

This will uniformly divide in to number of RDD

> NOTE : Same is applicable for below `DataFrame.randomSplit` as well

- You can also convert that in to `Dataframe` by giving schema to `RDD` and use like below example.. 
   `sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddOfRow, Schema)`

later you can call this method.

> DataFrame[] randomSplit(double[] weights) Randomly splits this
>   DataFrame with the provided weights.

- other thought I had is dividing based on number of Partitions...

i.e `RDD.mapPartitionWithIndex(....)`

for each partition you have an `Iterator` (can be converted in to RDD). you can have some thing like number of partitions = number of RDDs

Comment: sum of weights is greater than 1 then it will equally divide them as part of normalization

Comment: use `rdd.partitions.length` as weights if sum is more than 1 then it will automatically  normalizes and divide in to equal number of weights. I have done the same. it should work

Comment: updated my answer with a note : weights **weights for splits, will be normalized if they don't sum to 1**

Comment: Is it possible to splits rdd to equal size ,that means for example if number of records is 12  and  for k = 3 then each rdd has 4 records .

Comment: if your partitioning is correct then you will get approximately equal number of records in the above way